# Azure Cloud Services Slots

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I've got few Cloud Services that have both Production and Staging slots. Since I hadn't deploy the environment and I'm not aware of what exactly stands behind them - can I delete the Staging slots to lower the cost because they are billed the same as Production slots? And if I download the config files, would I be able eventually to import them back in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly deploy to the production slot of a Azure Cloud Service. If you have more than one role instance (you are running multiple role instances to get the stated SLA right?), Azure will automatically upgrade each role instance independently of one another.

While this saves you a little bit of money by not deploying to the staging slot, we found the staging slot deployment to work with our continuous integration strategy better.

Reference : [How to Manage Cloud Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-manage-portal)

Comment: how does this save you money by not deploying to a staging slot?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I delete the Staging slots to lower the cost because they are
>   billed the same as Production slots?

You should be able to delete staging slot without impacting the production slot. However if you have some users that are connecting to the staging slot, they will no longer be able to connect to the application once you delete the deployment from staging slot.

> And if I download the config files, would I be able eventually to
>   import them back in Azure?

Merely download the config file is not going to help as you would also need the package file. What you should do instead is invoke [`Get Deployment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj154121.aspx) Service Management API REST operation. What it will do is copy both the config file and package file in a storage account of your choice.

Comment: And when i get the files in the storage account - would I be able to redeploy this cloud service in future?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to do so.